# Convert ZipArchiveEntry to FileStream C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-ziparchive

I have a ZipArchiveEntry which is an Excel file and want to convert it to a FileStream. How can I do it? Also I don't have information about the path for the file. Basically this is the code I have:

```
   var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(InputStream);

   foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries)
   {
     using (var stream = entry.Open())
     {
       //Conversion stream => FileStream
     }
   }
```

Comment: Try using Memory Sream instead of FileStream.  What are you trying to do?  Write to a file or something else?  Maybe use StreamWriter instead.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the data in the excel to dataTable

Comment: Why do you need a `FileStream` what's wrong with just a generic `Stream`?

Comment: The method I'm using, uses FileStream and I didn't find a way to convert stream to DataTable

Comment: Its odd that it would take filestream rather than stream. Maybe you can change that function to take stream instead

Answer (score 2):

[Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-6.0) - Reads the bytes from the current stream and writes them to another stream. Both streams positions are advanced by the number of bytes copied.

```
var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(InputStream);

foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries)
{
    using (var fileStream =  new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
    using (var stream = entry.Open())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract entries into temp folder and work with them.

```cs
const string tempFolder = ".temp";

var entryFileStreams = new List<FileStream>();

using (var archive = new ZipArchive(InputStream))
{
    // extracting excel files into temp folder
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        string destinationFileName = Path.Combine(tempFolder, entry.Name);

        FileStream entryFileStream = File.Create(destinationFileName);
        Stream entryStream = entry.Open();

        entryStream.CopyTo(entryFileStream);
        entryFileStreams.Add(entryFileStream);
    }
}

// work with FileStream's
foreach (FileStream entryStream in entryFileStreams)
{
    DoSomething(entryStream);
}

// disposing FileStream's
entryFileStreams.ForEach(entryStream => entryStream.Dispose());

// deleting entry temp files
Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true);
```

Comment: dont forget to dispose entryStream!